# Switching from ODBC to OLEDB and getting "Object Required"

Tags: vba, vb6, odbc, oledb

I have been tasked with modifying some VBA code to switch from using an ODBC connection to using an OLEDB connection so we can just code a username and password into a subroutine.

I'm certainly not experienced with this but I think I'm managed to get the proper connection string for the new OLEDB connection.

I've tested the connection string in a standalone test sub and it worked fine.

I'm attempting to replace the previous ODBC connection strings in the code but I'm starting to get "Run-time error '424' Object required"

Here is the sub I am currently trying to get to work:

```
Sub getdata()
Dim tableName As String
Dim tableRecords As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Cnxn2 As ADODB.Connection 

tableName = "TABLE_NAME"

Set Cnxn2 = New ADODB.Connection

'Old Connection String Using ODBC
'Cnxn2.ConnectionString = "Data Source='DATASOURCE';" '& "Integrated Security = SSPI;"

'New Connection String Using OLEDB
Cnxn2.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=SERVER\INSTANCE;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;"

Cnxn2.ConnectionTimeout = 30
Cnxn2.Open
tableRecords.Open tableName, Cnxn2, adUseClient, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

With tableRecords
ReturnData.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset tableRecords(10)

.Close
End With
        Cnxn2.Close

        Set Cnxn2 = Nothing
        Set tableRecords = Nothing
    End Sub
```

The error is highlighting the line stating "ReturnData.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset tableRecords(1)

Why am I getting Object Required errors when I only changed the connection string?

Note: There was a very similar sub in the code in another location and I simply deleted the "ReturnData." from the previously mentioned line and it seemed to start working. If I do that here though I get this:
Run-time error '430': Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

Any help into why switching to OLEDB is breaking this sub is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you code ReturnData is not being created or anything, unless you are declaring it to be global variable else where. I imagine you are doing this in Excel. In which case replace `ReturnData.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset tableRecords(10)`
with something like

```
activeworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset tableRecords(10)
```

EDIT. Managed to replicate it and then fixed it. Try this.

replace `ReturnData.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset tableRecords(10)`
with something like

```
activeworkbook.sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset tableRecords
```

Comment: When I change it that way I start getting the automation error again. Run-time error '430': Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

Comment: are you running it in excel? Is it in a standard module or Class module?

Comment: Also do you have any references in VBA which is missing or to a certain file?

Comment: I'm running it in a standard module in excel. There are references within the excel file that point to other excel files. But for now I'm just running this individual sub. It should simply pull some data from the recordset and paste it into sheet1

Comment: Try change "sqloledb" in the connection string to "SQLNCLI11" You may have to see if it is installed though. As it is using the SQL Server Native Client 11 to connect. Trying to replicate your problem but so far works fine on mine. WIll keep trying though

Comment: That resolved the Automation error and I see data being copied to the sheet. Do you know what the (10) subset represented on the record set?

Comment: I havent seen it before and didnt actually notice it to start with. But I am guessing that it might of been an array of recordsets. Then it was trying to get the 11th element of the array into the recordset. However that could be totally wrong. Just my educated guess at this point